# Can I add factory class to custom extension point

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-mars

Creating the extension point:
[image: Picture]

Attach to extension point class:
[image: Picture]

Can I add factory class to the custom extension point, which returns a different class depending on some rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your class a factory it can implement the `IExecutableExtensionFactory` class, The Eclipse extension manager will call the

```
public Object create() throws CoreException
```

method to ask your factory to create the extension class.

Many factory classes also implement `IExecutableExtension` which has the single method:

```
public void setInitializationData(IConfigurationElement config, String propertyName, Object data) throws CoreException
```

The extension manager will call `setInitializationData` before calling `create`. It gives you the entire configuration element from the plugin.xml so you can look at any attributes you want.